# Stopping another class main method with Reflection

Tags: java, reflection

So currently I execute the mainclass of the other file by going like this.

```
Client.main(new String[]{"a", "a"});
```

Is there anyway to "stop" or "exit" that class? Or tell that main to stop running?

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/interrupt.html

Comment: What is the relevance of reflection here?